# Self-signed certification error when running Okta flask integration sample

Tags: python, flask, python-requests, ssl-certificate, okta-api

Self-signed certification error when trying to execute the sample Flask and Okta integration program on work computer.

I am learning to integrate Okta SSO in Flask using Pycharm IDE. I am following the sample tutorial on  https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/07/12/flask-tutorial-simple-user-registration-and-login.

After I run program and enter my account username and password on the Okta sign-in page, it throws certification error stating that there was a self-signed certificate in the certificates chain. I have tried disabling the ssl context using code below.

But that doesn't work either. If I enter the wrong email and password, it just gives me invalid credentials notification but doesn't throw the certification error. Its only after entering the right username and password does it throw the error.

I have read thru several forums and thread on several different websites, but seems like there is no other person facing similar issue.

The same program works on my personal computer. My work computer has other certificates for SSO and other device controls. Please let me know if you can help me anyway. Thank you in advance.

```
try:
  _create_unverified_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
except AttributeError:
  # Legacy Python that doesn’t verify HTTPS certificates by default
  pass
else:
  # Handle target environment that doesn’t support HTTPS verification
  ssl._create_default_https_context =     _create_unverified_https_context
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a specific and clear solution, but changing the python version to an older version and back to newest version and re-install flaskoidc package did the trick.

Thank you all!